# Can't apply user input in codenvy

Tags: java.util.scanner, codenvy

I've been going crazy trying to research the answer to this and am getting nowhere!!!

I'm testing out codenvy to improve on an online sandbox for my computer science high school students. I wrote a test program to get familiar with codenvy and ran into some user input issues.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("Hello Worldie!");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a #");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("is this your card...." + number);
        //input.close();
    }
}
```

My errors/output:

```
command: cd /projects/test javac -classpath /projects/test: -sourcepath src: -d /projects/test/bin src/Main.java java -classpath /projects/test:/projects/test/bin Main
Hello World!
Hello Worldie!
Enter a #
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Can someone help me with what I'm missing? I'm wondering if it's some codenvy feature that I have to adjust?

Thanks,
core

Comment: The Scanner has nothing in it because it looks like Codenvy doesn't provide a STDIN for console apps. There may be workarounds. Search "codenvy stdin"

Comment: It's a known Codenvy bug: https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues/984

Comment: Try running your jar file after building:
    
    java -jar console-java-simple/target/console-java-simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: So Hakan, codenvy is presently incapable of allowing user input from the Run button on their workspace controls? If (if I'm understanding this correctly) user input only works if I run my program through the built in terminal, then can someone help me with how to run from terminal? I've entered "ls" into terminal and I see the names of all my projects in that workspace. What command would run my project called "test"?

Comment: I ran the snapshot line in terminal and got: Error: Unable to access jarfile console-java-simple/target/console-java-simple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Outside of that actual coding, I'm completely outside of my element here.